# (pre)cursive chmod on created directory in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-permissions, chmod

I've got a Python script that is creating a rather lengthy directory structure.  Can someone help explain how to successfully 'chmod' several levels back from the directory created?  For example, I threw together this small bit of code to test it out.  If I run the following code:

```
log_dir = "/home/milnuts/Public/test1/test2"

if not os.path.exists(log_dir):
    os.makedirs(log_dir)
    os.chmod(log_dir, 0664)
```

You can see here that I get the correct permissions set for /test2, but I'd like to set them for /test1 as well.  Is there any simple way to do this?

```
~/Public> ll 
total 4 drwxr-s--- 3 milnuts eng 4096 Aug 14 11:15 test1 
~/Public> ll test1 
total 4 drw-rw-r-- 2 milnuts eng 4096 Aug 14 11:15 test2
```

Comment: Is this possibly a two step process where I use os.makdirs and os.chmod at the highest level in the directory structure where I want the permissions changed, in this case /test1.  If I could then somehow create /test2 under /test1 and inherit its permissions, I suppose that would be good enough too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`os.makedirs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs) takes an optional `mode` argument that sets the mode of the created directories.

```
os.makedirs(log_dir, 0o664)
```